# Compare datetime, only show time if Ymd are same

Tags: php, datetime, compare, datediff

I have 2 values stored in a database. One is a startdate, the other an enddate.

Now when the Year, month and date of the 2 are equal. I would like the enddate to only show the time.

For example

maandag 16 juni 14:06 tot maandag 16 juni 14:15

would be

maandag 16 juni 14:06 tot 14:15.

I'm pretty new at PHP. I've tried the following statement, but i'm pretty sure it's incorrect:$

```
<?php if($item->startdate("Ymd") == ($item->enddate("Ymd"))): ?>
```

The type of the values are DateTime

Comment: what is the type of the values stored in the database? String or DateTime

Comment: The type of the values are DateTime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also try using the [substr](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php)-function, only comparing portions of the variables:

```
if(substr($item->startdate, 0, 10) == substr($item->enddate, 0, 10))
```

Here we compare the first ten characters (*YYYY-MM-DD*) of `$item->startdate` and `$item->enddate`.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
if(date('Ymd',strtotime($item->startdate)) == date('Ymd',strtotime($item->enddate))) :
```

The date function should take almost any data format and reformat it to the format you give it i.e. 'Ymd'

[PHP Manual for the date() function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Comment: I'm getting the error : "ErrorException [ Notice ]: A non well formed numeric value encountered"

Comment: Answer @kpp's question. What is the format of startdate and enddate in your database? Add this to your question, not as a comment.

Comment: Display the values of startdate and enddate like this var_dump($item); and put that info in the question also

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php if(date('Y-m-d',strtotime($item->startdate) == date('Y-m-d',strtotime($item->enddate))) : ?>
```

Comment: Mind you explaining your solution please?